# I can't scroll, could few minutes ago

Tags: html, css

I'm using Laravel to make some pages, one of them has next and previous page button, that work, and for dark reasons, I can't scroll using scroll wheel anymore. I can click on the side bar of the browser and scroll this way, but scroll wheel won't do anything for now (and it's not a broken wheel, other sites work well).

The only thing I changed right before it happened is that I moved some view code in a blade template.

I tried this, with no succes:

```
html {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

However, this kinda works :

```
* {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

But i get scroll bar on container, makes the page aweful.
What could be the reason to this ? And if somehow it keep happening, can I hide side scroll bars ?
(I also cleared cache)

Comment: Can you replicate this in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) at all?

Comment: Laravel related don't fit something like that, there's thing going on between views and controller and I don't know how to do it (or if I even can)

Comment: The issue is related to the HTML output from your view somewhere along the lines. You can try to view source in the browser of the page that's causing the issue, copy and paste the HTML and assets onto JSfiddle for us to look at - it's difficult for anyone else to debug without that unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, sure ^^

Anyway i pasted the body of the source code, along with the css, in fiddle's editor, and this is what came out... and it scroll with the scroll wheel though.
(Don't mind the languages, nor this hell of a nav menu)

https://jsfiddle.net/afdw2yfd/

And last thing: my pages can actually scroll but I have to click on the side scroll bar to do so, can't scroll with the wheel...

Comment: No big deal, closed tab and reopened... that's it, works perfectly fine...
I downvoted myself, I'm the clumsy guy >.<